# How to Test Angular2 / TypeScript HTTPService without Mock

Tags: testing, typescript, angular, integration-testing

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  result: any;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

   public postRequest(){
       return this.http.get('http://httpbin.org/get');    
  }
}
```

Above is my code, here is my Test:

I ***do not want to mock*** anything, just test the real http connection.

## Edit - New service.spec file:

```
import {beforeEachProviders, beforeEach, it, describe, expect, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpService} from '../../providers/http-service/http-service';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {Goal} from '../../providers/goal/goal';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from '@angular/http';

describe('Http Service Test', () => {

      beforeEachProviders(() => {
        return [
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            HttpService
        ];
    });

    it('should return response when subscribed to postRequest',
        inject([HttpService], (httpService: HttpService) => {

            httpService.postRequest().subscribe((res) => {
                expect(res.text()).toBe('hello raja');
            }); 
    }));
});
```

These are my errors in karma console:

```
28 06 2016 14:33:32.067:ERROR [Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.4) | Http Service Test | should return response when subscribed to postRequest]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null
    at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/vy/18sb1wqs60g734bhr75cw9_r0000gn/T/9b9439f5f9c1590d3052594bcae9e877.browserify?26719cf22e6406ebc638b6b187c777666dcc5698:36568:81)
    at XHRBackend.createConnection (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/vy/18sb1wqs60g734bhr75cw9_r0000gn/T/9b9439f5f9c1590d3052594bcae9e877.browserify?26719cf22e6406ebc638b6b187c777666dcc5698:36583:28)
    at httpRequest (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/vy/18sb1wqs60g734bhr75cw9_r0000gn/T/9b9439f5f9c1590d3052594bcae9e877.browserify?26719cf22e6406ebc638b6b187c777666dcc5698:37476:20)
```

Comment: if you are testing beyond the boundaries of your classes and reaching other external services is not an unit test, probably you want an Integration test.

Comment: It is legitimate to construct integration testing through a unit testing framework. Commentators please provide answer rather than banging with unit testing and mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to configure providers for the mock HTTP backend:

```
describe('HttpService Tests', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
      HttpService
   ];
});
```

Then you can use the mock backend this way:

```
mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
  (connection: MockConnection) => {
    if (connection.request.url === 'file1.json') {
      // Simulate an error
      var err = new ResponseError();
      err.status = 404;
      connection.mockError(<Error>err);
    } else {
      // Simulate a successful response
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(
        new ResponseOptions({
          body: ['i love angular2']
        })));
    }
  });

httpService.postRequest().subscribe((res:Respsone) => {
  expect(res.text()).toBe('hello raja');
});
```

**Edit**

If you want to test with real connection, use the classical HTTP_PROVIDERS only:

```
describe('HttpService Tests', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      HttpService
   ];
});
```

**Edit1**

Since your call is asynchronous, you could use `async`:

```
it('should return response when subscribed to postRequest',
    async(inject([HttpService], (httpService: HttpService) => {

        httpService.postRequest().subscribe((res) => {
            expect(res.text()).toBe('hello raja');
        }); 
})));
```

Comment: Ok I updated my Question with new code from your reply. Can you confirm that is working? (I still get bundle errors in karma)

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use? Perhaps you could use `async`... I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Latest Version of angular2.(RC1 2.0.0) I am really greatful for your help! I will now test your suggestion. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987391/jasmine-gives-cannot-read-property-getxhr-of-null-for-angular-2-unit-test

Comment: Ok with the Link I posted, the test is now passing, but my "res" / result is empty. Any ideas? And any luck with RC3?

Comment: I would debug your test. I mean start karma without the `singleRun` option set to `true` and click on the debug button in the browser. Then you can add breakpoints in both service and test to see the HTTP request...

Comment: Yes exactly. "without the singleRun option set to true" ;-)

Comment: I had tested with rc1, 2 and 4, and still got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null"

Comment: HTTP_PROVIDERS is deprecated, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239197/angular2-import-http-providers-error

Answer (score 1):

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/MockBackend-class.html

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend} from '@angular/http/testing';
it('should get some data', inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async) => {
  var connection;
  var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
    MockBackend,
    {provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
      return new Http(backend, options);
    }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]}]);
  var http = injector.get(Http);
  var backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
  //Assign any newly-created connection to local variable
  backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
    async.done();
  });
  connection.mockRespond(new Response('awesome'));
}));
```

and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/MockConnection-class.html

```
var connection;
backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
http.request('data.json').subscribe(res => console.log(res.text()));
connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: 'fake response' }))); //logs
'fake response'
```

Comment: No, No I expicity NO NOT want to mock... ;D

Comment: What's the problem then? If you don't mock `Http` then it's not an unit test but an integration test.

Comment: My code has some basic TypeScript / Angular2 malunderstandings. I do not know which. I can plunkr this for you.