# angular2 import HTTP_PROVIDERS error

Tags: angular

angular2 import HTTP_PROVIDERS

error message >>
@angular/http/index"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NoticeService} from './products/product.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <pm-products></pm-products>
  `,
  providers: [NoticeService, HTTP_PROVIDERS] 
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need HTTP_PROVIDERS anymore (deprecated).  Import the http module instead.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {  HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule  
        ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: As I know right it's necessary to use `http.get` and `http.post` methods?